# How to filter by parent document in SonataAdmin Doctrine2 PHPCR Admin

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin, doctrine-phpcr

It is my first simple project on SymfonyCMF.
In my project i have a lot of 'profile' documents(in term of phpcr). Each profile belongs to specific 'department'(parent document). (In phpcr each document must have parent document.)
In admin panel (SonataAdmin) i can list all 'profiles' using configureListFields function. I can filter them by 'profile' properties using configureDatagridFilters function.
But, cant figure out how to filter 'profile' by its parent 'department' document.

```
        protected function configureDatagridFilters(DatagridMapper $datagridMapper)
    {
        $datagridMapper
            ->add('name','doctrine_phpcr_string')
            ->add('title', 'doctrine_phpcr_string')
            ->add('parent') <--- Need to filter  by parent !
          ;
    }
```

Tried to implement custom callback filter function from SonataAdmin [documentation](https://sonata-project.org/bundles/doctrine-phpcr-admin/1-x/doc/reference/filter_field_definition.html):

```
    protected function configureDatagridFilters(DatagridMapper $datagridMapper)
    {
        $datagridMapper

            ->add('parent', 'doctrine_phpcr_callback', array(
                'callback' => function($queryBuilder, $alias, $field, $data) {
                    if (!$data || !is_array($data) || !array_key_exists('value', $data)) {
                        return;
                    }

                    $queryBuilder = $proxyQuery->getQueryBuilder();
                    $eb = $queryBuilder->expr();

                    $queryBuilder->andWhere($eb->eq($field, $data['value']));

                    return true;
                },
                'field_type' => 'checkbox'
            ))
        ;
    }
```

But, first i got an error related to $proxyQuery, $queryBuilder->expr(). Second i have no idea how to properly query and filter by parent ((.
Thanx in advance.

**SOLVED thanx to @Bilel Noômene**
The final answer is

```
    protected function configureDatagridFilters(DatagridMapper $datagridMapper)
{

    $datagridMapper->add('parent', 'doctrine_phpcr_callback', array('callback' =>
        function ($proxyQuery, $alias, $field, $data) {
            if (!$data || !is_array($data) || !array_key_exists('value', $data) || !$data['value']) {
                return;
            }


            $queryBuilder = $proxyQuery->getQueryBuilder();

            $queryBuilder->from($alias)
                ->joinInner()
                ->left()->document(Profile::class, $alias)->end()
                ->right()->document(Department::class, 'd')->end()
                ->condition()->child($alias, 'd')->end();

            $queryBuilder->andWhere()->same($data['value']->getId(), 'd')->end();

            return true;
        }
    ), DocumentType::class, array('class'=>Department::class));

    parent::configureDatagridFilters($datagridMapper);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example of the documentation doesn't seem to be working correctly. For your case, try this code.

```
public function configureDatagridFilters(DatagridMapper $datagridMapper)
{
    $datagridMapper->add('parent', 'doctrine_phpcr_callback', array('callback' =>
        function ($proxyQuery, $alias, $field, $data) {
            if (!$data || !is_array($data) || !array_key_exists('value', $data) || !$data['value']) {
                return;
            }

            $queryBuilder = $proxyQuery->getQueryBuilder();

            $queryBuilder->from($alias)
                ->joinInner()
                ->left()->document(Profile::class, $alias)->end()
                ->right()->document(Department::class, 'd')->end()
                ->condition()->child($alias, 'd')->end();
            $queryBuilder->andWhere()->same($data['value']->getId(), 'd')->end();

            return true;
        }
    ), 'phpcr_document', array('class' => Department::class));

    parent::configureDatagridFilters($datagridMapper);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your responce.  But get error ` "Could not load type 'phpcr_document'
500 Internal Server Error - InvalidArgumentException" `

Comment: Figured out how to list Departments in combobox, changed 'phpcr_document' --> 'DocumentType::class'. But, get another error 'QueryBuilder node "From" must have at least "1" child nodes of type "source". "0" given.'